# Pasar un List de una clase a otra en Android

Tags: java, android, lista

Estoy intetando tener varios valores en un List y dentro de este también habrá otra lista, para ello cree una clase modelo y luego esta usarla con un List para guardar los diferentes datos. Todo marcha bien, guardo todos los datos normal, pero al momento de consumir esos datos, el único que no llega son los datos contenidos dentro de la lista de la clase modelo, a continuación dejo mi código:

```
public class Modelo {

public String IdActi;
int Duracion, Costo;
public List<String> Prreq = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Clase modelo**

```
public Modelo(){

}

public Modelo(String idActi, int duracion, int costo, List<String> prreq) {
    IdActi = idActi;
    Duracion = duracion;
    Costo = costo;
    Prreq = prreq;
    Log.i("Actvidad tamano", ""+Prreq.size());

}

}
```

**Clase principal**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private List<Modelo> Actividades;
private List<String> Prerreq = new ArrayList<String>();

private EditText nom,dur,cost,pre;
private Button AgregarPre,AgregarActividad,Generar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Actividades = new ArrayList<>();

    nom=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Id);
    dur=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Duracion);
    cost=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Costo);
    pre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Prreq);

    AgregarPre=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgregarPre);
    AgregarActividad=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgregarActividad);
    Generar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar);

    AgregarPre.setOnClickListener(this);
    AgregarActividad.setOnClickListener(this);
    Generar.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view==AgregarPre){
        Prerreq.add(pre.getText().toString());
    }
    if (view==AgregarActividad){

        Actividades.add(new Modelo(nom.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(dur.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(cost.getText().toString()),  Prerreq));
        int cont2=Prerreq.size();
        for (int b=0;b<cont2;b++) {
            Log.i("Actvidad prerreq", Prerreq.get(b));
        }


        Prerreq.clear();
    }
    if (view==Generar){
        int cont=Actividades.size();
        String id;StringBuilder pre= new StringBuilder();
        int du,co;

        for (int a=0;a<cont;a++){
            int cont2=Actividades.get(a).Prreq.size();
            Log.i("Actvidad tamano", ""+Actividades.get(0).Prreq.size());
            id=Actividades.get(a).IdActi;
            du=Actividades.get(a).Duracion;
            co=Actividades.get(a).Costo;
            for (int b=0;b<cont2;b++) {
                pre.append(Actividades.get(a).Prreq.get(b)).append(", ");
            }
            Log.i("Actvidad",id+", "+du+", "+co+", "+pre);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Aqui agrego los elementos de la lista**

```
 Actividades.add(new Modelo(nom.getText().toString(),Integer.valueOf(dur.getText().toString()),
                Integer.valueOf(cost.getText().toString()),  Prerreq));
```

**Y de esta forma consumo los datos para mostrarlos en consola**

```
int cont=Actividades.size();
        String id;StringBuilder pre= new StringBuilder();
        int du,co;

        for (int a=0;a<cont;a++){
            int cont2=Actividades.get(a).Prreq.size();
            Log.i("Actvidad tamano", ""+Actividades.get(0).Prreq.size());
            id=Actividades.get(a).IdActi;
            du=Actividades.get(a).Duracion;
            co=Actividades.get(a).Costo;
            for (int b=0;b<cont2;b++) {
                pre.append(Actividades.get(a).Prreq.get(b)).append(", ");
            }
            Log.i("Actvidad",id+", "+du+", "+co+", "+pre);
```

Comment: Deberías usar `parseInt` en lugar de `valueOf` para pasar los parámetros `int` a la clase, por ejemplo: `Integer.parseInt(dur.getText().toString()),`  y por favor, usa variables... tu código es ilegible en varios puntos. Si no funciona, comenta lo que hay en tu ¿lista `Actividades`?, muestra cómo creas ese objeto y también respeta la *convención de nombres*. No se sabe si `Actividades` es una clase o es tu lista. La convención de nombres indica que sólo los nombres de clase se escriban con la 1ª letra en mayúsculas (y la 1ª letra de cada palabra). Tu código es muy confuso.

Comment: Actvidades es una lista señor. Perdón por todos mis errores en el código pero lo he estado haciendo solo de prueba para ver si lo aplico en otro código que tengo. Agregue todo el codigo completo de la clase MainActivity, puse partes especificas de la clase en vez cosa que para alguien que va analizar el codigo es algo molesto xD me disculpo por ello.